# How to move/promote/merge/add my StackOverflow question to one of the new sites?

Tags: discussion, site-crossover

What to do if I have a SO question which has some perfectly satisfactory answers (plus I have accepted one of them) from a few months ago ... but which would work even better on one of the new sites. Who knows, I might get some additional valid answers?

Do I add the question in its entirety to the new site? Or do I add a brief question and link to the original on SO? Or do I do nothing, since I got - basically - some decent answers first time round?

Example: [Using a "hyperlink" effect in Winforms applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310272) seems this would be better asked on the UI site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually people only repost if their problem wasn't solved on the first site, but you can if you want to. You should repost the question in its entirety on UI so it can stand alone there, but include a link somewhere to the original question on SO since the question text is now licensed as cc-wiki with [attribution required](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)

Comment: The issue with crossposting an already solved problem is that new people will just copy and paste from the original question and rep farm.